# getJSON request functioning slowly

Tags: jquery

I'm using a getJSON request to display a random image on hover. My problem is that each image is loading slowly, I believe because the JSON request is happening on each hover. Any suggestions on how I could make this request work quicker? Many thanks :)

```
  $.getJSON('images.json', function(result) {
    $('#imagehover').on('mouseenter', function() {
      var index = Math.floor(result.url.length * Math.random());
      $("#imageresult").html($('<img>', {src: result.url[index]}));
    });
  });
```

Comment: _"I believe because the JSON request is happening on each hover"_  it's not

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preloading images with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476679/preloading-images-with-jquery)

Comment: How large are your images and how many do you expect to have ?

Comment: There are about 70 images around 400kb. What if the data was stored in a variable, would the images be preloaded?